# how to start writing a simple editor

Tags: text-editor

I want to have a very simple editor for my website that i wrote a minimal cms for.
I do not have any experience in javascript but it's obviously something i'll have to learn sooner or later anyway, i'm fairly proficient in php.
The editor i need is mostly for me, i might extend it some for a possible comments section that might add later, but this is not a priority. Therefore i don't need a wysiwyg editor, something that's easy to use and just parsing the textarea text in php would be sufficient.
Now my question is should I write something in php to parse text or should i try to write something in javascript that would allow me to put some buttons into the editor and perhaps make it far easier to use and/or parse.

don't know how to tag this.

Comment: Moving this to StackOverflow. I'm not sure if this question in its current form will stay open as it can be considered subjective.

Comment: What would an editor written in PHP do? It'd just be a textbox. All the stuff you do with an editor requires the ability to know where the mouse cursor is and what text is highlighted... the server doesn't know that after you submit a form.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what functionality you need this text editor to do? Like I need it to do x, y and z. Is this better accomplished server side (php) or client side (js)?

Comment: I just need to insert content into a database for my minimal cms, for that i want to be able to chose if i want to display html tags or have them parsed, sometimes i need both of those in the same paragraph.  now i'm wondering if i have to parse the text in the textbox or if i could write some code in javascript that would take care of it and if it would be easier that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at this: http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/
It runs on top of [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).  JQuery is cross-platform and easy to get so the jHtmlArea Editor *should* work well on mutliple platforms also.